# Is there a way to integrate Pandas into tableau?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, tableau-api, data-analysis

I've been using tableau for a few months now and it really is a great visualization tool. However, I feel limited because I am more familiar with the pandas library and I feel more powerful on pandas. Is there a way to integrate python into Tableau so I work on one environment, instead of constantly exporting data from Pandas and re-importing it into tableau?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look into plotly's dash or altair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** For the wording of your question - **No**, `pandas` isn't specifically integrated. But Python is (sort of).

You may want to look into leveraging [TabPy](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/11/leverage-power-python-tableau-tabpy-62077), but again this isn't very `pandas` specific. but this is sort of an ETL question. Tableau has something called Extracts and you can [refresh them](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_push.html) straight from Server.

I had an automated job using an ETL tool (think Data Pipelines or software like SSIS/Alteryx) which uses Python code to load a data format that Tableau can read. Tableau can read from literally hundreds of sources so this isn't too difficult.

But the general Idea is:

1. Something to Kick off code
2. Run Code
3. Code dumps data to format (file or database-like environment)
4. Tableau Reads/Extracts data
5. ??
6. Profit

If you truly want to be in *one* environment, there are many options such as [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/), [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), and/or [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/) Matplotlib is the "source" for most visualizations in Python, so that is always a good one to learn. Seaborn makes matplot a little easier to read/write and plot.ly has dashboarding/hosting options built in to give a Tableau feel.

Tableau also has a new tool called [Tableau Prep](https://www.tableau.com/products/prep) that can do *some* of the things pandas can do (you'll never beat code with a software tool). So this can also satisfy your one-environment requirement.

Comment: You could simplify a few of the steps above if you use pantab - https://pantab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/